# Multiple correlated subqueries are killing SQL Server. How to avoid this?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables and I need to generate report from them. 
I wrote this query that solves my task in smaller databases, but if amount of records exceeds 5-6 millions performance of the query becomes very poor

```
insert into Reconcile ([Account], [Beginning balance], [Turnover TB], [Turnover JE], [Diff], [Ending balance], [Ending balance client]) 
select 
    [GL Account Number ], 
    [Functional Beginning Balance], 
    (case when  (select COUNT([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='S' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) = 0 
        then 0 
    else (select SUM([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='S' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) end 
    + case when (select COUNT([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='H' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) = 0 
        then 0 
    else (select SUM([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='H' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) end), 
    [Turnover], 
    ((case when (select COUNT([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='S' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) = 0 
        then 0 
    else (select SUM([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='S' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) end 
    + case when (select COUNT([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='H' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) = 0 
        then 0 
    else (select SUM([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='H' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) end) - ([Turnover])), 
    ([Functional Beginning Balance] + 
    (case when (select COUNT([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='S' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) = 0 
        then 0 
    else (select SUM([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='S' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) end 
    + case when (select COUNT([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='H' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) = 0 
        then 0 
    else (select SUM([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='H' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) end)), 
    [Functional Ending Balance] 
from TB LEFT JOIN JE je 
ON TB.[GL Account Number ]=[HKONT]
group by [GL Account Number ], [Functional Beginning Balance], [Turnover], [Functional Ending Balance], [HKONT]
```

I know that the problem is in multiple repetitive subqueries, but I am pretty new with tsql and I don't know how to run this subquery once for each record in dataset and then only use it's return value in other occurencies, that use that subquery

```
(case when  (select COUNT([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='S' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) = 0 
        then 0 
    else (select SUM([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='S' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) end 
    + case when (select COUNT([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='H' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) = 0 
        then 0 
    else (select SUM([DMBTR]) from JE where [SHKZG]='H' and je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) end)
```

How to optimize this query?

Comment: A query can't kill SQL Server. A bad query will run slowly though. In this case you don't have *one* query, you have 9 individual queries that scan the entire table in the select statement, which means they are *repeated* for every row that comes from the `FROM` clause. That could be 5M rows raised to the ninth power. Just don't do that

Comment: If you have a lot of data, use a proper reporting schema. A star schema is ideal. Right now you are trying to perform the job of an ETL script in the query itself.

Comment: Rewrite it. Don't use such subqueries. Use a proper reporting table and schema. You can't expect people to design the database for you, espedcially when the table schemas are missing and the purpose of the report is unknown. One would have to spend a few hours trying to understand what that does. *WHY* are you using subqueries at all, instead of adding the `SHKZG` column to the GROUP BY clause? Why are you joining with HKONT in the *subqueries* instead of the JOIN?

Comment: BTW I'm writing queries that join ledgers and accounts right now. I can't even understand what those acronyms are. What I would do in general would be to create a fact table with every line item and lookup relations to invoice type, line item type tables etc. You should be able to use a *simple* GROUP BY and aggregates. Then I'd write (actuall I *am* writing) an SSIS job or SQL script that generates the rows I want to insert into the reporting table. I'd NEVER query the invoice tables themselves

Comment: T-SQL in SqlServer uses statistical optimization.  As such, there is nothing specifically wrong with subqueries, and despite what you may have heard they do not always (or even normally) result in separate scans for every source row.  However it depends on a lot of things, such as their complexity (including whether you are querying actual tables, or something more complicated such as views), the available indexes, what version of SQL Server etc.  However, we cannot really tell what the problem is unless you post the query plan for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **How to optimize this query?**

**Well Try following:**

- Avoid any sub queries.
- Replace sub queries with derived tables where possible.
- Use grouping effectively.
- Avoid duplicate code.

That being said,

**Try following query.**

```
INSERT INTO Reconcile ([Account], [Beginning balance], [Turnover TB], [Turnover JE], [Diff], [Ending balance], [Ending balance client]) 
SELECT 
    [GL Account Number ], 

    [Functional Beginning Balance], 

    (CASE WHEN  ISNULL(JE_S.DMBTR_COUNT, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(JE_S.DMBTR_SUM, 0) END 
    + CASE WHEN ISNULL(JE_H.DMBTR_COUNT, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(JE_H.DMBTR_SUM, 0) END), 

    [Turnover], 

    ((CASE WHEN ISNULL(JE_S.DMBTR_COUNT, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(JE_S.DMBTR_SUM, 0) END 
    + CASE WHEN ISNULL(JE_H.DMBTR_COUNT, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(JE_H.DMBTR_SUM, 0) END) 
    - ([Turnover])), 

    ([Functional Beginning Balance] 
    + (CASE WHEN ISNULL(JE_S.DMBTR_COUNT, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(JE_S.DMBTR_SUM, 0) END 
    + CASE WHEN ISNULL(JE_H.DMBTR_COUNT, 0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ISNULL(JE_H.DMBTR_SUM, 0) END)), 

    [Functional Ending Balance] 

FROM TB LEFT JOIN JE je 
ON TB.[GL Account Number ]=[HKONT]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [HKONT], COUNT([DMBTR]) DMBTR_COUNT, SUM([DMBTR]) DMBTR_SUM  FROM JE WHERE [SHKZG]='S' GROUP BY [HKONT]) JE_S
ON [GL Account Number ] = JE_S.[HKONT]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT [HKONT], COUNT([DMBTR]) DMBTR_COUNT, SUM([DMBTR]) DMBTR_SUM  FROM JE WHERE [SHKZG]='H' GROUP BY [HKONT]) JE_H
ON [GL Account Number ] = JE_S.[HKONT]
GROUP BY [GL Account Number ], [Functional Beginning Balance], [Turnover], [Functional Ending Balance], [HKONT]
```

I have just tried to do some quick find and replace with your query. 
Let me know if it works for you.

This could be further optimized surely. Though, I will leave it for you to explore.

Try to google or check some microsoft technet details on the subject for further learning.

**Below are some sample articles:**

1. [Query Performance Tuning guide - Microsot Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172984(v=sql.110).aspx)
2. [Difference between subqueries and derived tables](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/26/sql-subqueries-and-derived-tables/)

Comment: @whyiamhere - Why do you have that additional left outer join with JE? I kept it as it is as I was not sure of its usage.

Answer (score 0):

Get your sums once and then join to it

```
declare @JEsum table (SHKZG varchar(20), GLAccountNumber varchar(20), cnt int
                      , primary key (SHKZG, GLAccountNumber));
insert into @JEsum (SHKZG, GLAccountNumber, cnt) 
select [SHKZG], [GL Account Number ], count([DMBTR]) as cnt 
from TB LEFT JOIN JE 
ON TB.[GL Account Number ]=[HKONT] 
where [SHKZG] in ('s', 'h')
group by [SHKZG], [GL Account Number ]
```

Your query is hard to read.  Always include table name with column so people know where it came from.  Using JE multiple spots without alias is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to match up the 4 subqueries that you were running in each select statement and then use them in `APPLY` statements (which works pretty well for subqueries from my experiences).

```
SELECT 
    [GL Account Number ] AS [Account], 
    [Functional Beginning Balance] AS [Beginning balance], 
    (CASE       WHEN q1.[Count] = 0 THEN 0      ELSE q2.[Sum] END +     CASE        WHEN q4.[Count] = 0 THEN 0          ELSE q3.[Sum] END) as [Turnover TB],    [Turnover] AS [Turnover JE], 
    (   (CASE       WHEN q1.[Count] = 0 THEN 0          ELSE q2.[Sum] END +     CASE        WHEN q4.[Count] = 0 THEN 0          ELSE q3.[Sum] END) - ([Turnover])) AS [Diff], 
    ([Functional Beginning Balance] + 
    (   CASE        WHEN q1.[Count] = 0 THEN 0          ELSE q2.[Sum] END +     CASE        WHEN q4.[Count] = 0 THEN 0          ELSE q3.[Sum] END)) AS [Ending balance], 
    [Functional Ending Balance] AS [Ending balance client]
FROM TB LEFT JOIN JE je ON TB.[GL Account Number ]=[HKONT]
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT([DMBTR]) AS [Count]   FROM JE where [SHKZG]='S' AND je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) AS q1
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM([DMBTR]) AS [Sum]       FROM JE where [SHKZG]='S' AND je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) AS q2
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM([DMBTR]) AS [Sum]       FROM JE where [SHKZG]='H' AND je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) AS q3
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT([DMBTR]) AS [Count]   FROM JE where [SHKZG]='H' AND je.[HKONT]=[GL Account Number ]) AS q4
GROUP BY [GL Account Number ], [Functional Beginning Balance], [Turnover], [Functional Ending Balance], [HKONT]
```

You may need to add a combination of a `COALESCE` or an `IS NOT NULL` or `> 0` in order to accomplish what you want.

In addition,why are you completing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in your original `FROM` statement for `TB` and `JE`? Each subquery is looking at the field of the table on the right side of the left outer join.